# Is it possible to add your sidebar in your section? WordPress, Theme Customizer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

How add your sidebar in your section?
I have my sidebar:

```
function register_my_widgets(){
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Block 1 to Slide 2',
    'id' => 'homepage-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<p class="homepage-widget-block">',
    'after_widget' => '</p>',
    'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
) );
```

I have my section in customizer:

```
$wp_customize->add_section('example_section_one', array(
    'title' => 'Slide 2,
    'priority' => '',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
));
```

All widgets fall into the category of "widgets". How to get around it and add the widget to the  your section in theme customizer?

And is it possible to add a section in section in customizer?

Comment: What is that you are trying to do with your sidebar that you need to show it in a different section rather than the more intuitive "Widgets" section?

If you could describe in more details, perhaps we can try some solution

Comment: @shariqkhan Yes, I need to show sidebar in a different section.

Comment: Yes, I got that. What I am asking is is there any spefic reason why you are trying to show in a different section.
Your line of thought would help in bringing a solution

Comment: @shariqkhan I want to make a more clear structure of settings for my theme, the main page has the first section, the first section has the block in this block have widgets. I want to reflect that in the theme settings, to make their more structured.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'shk_so42130318', array(
    'title'          => __( 'My Custom Sidebar section', 'dreamglutes' )
) );
```

Next, use this filter:

```
function reassign_sidebar_panel( $section_args, $section_id, $sidebar_id ) {
    $section_args['panel'] = 'shk_so42130318';
    return $section_args;
}
add_filter( 'customizer_widgets_section_args', 'reassign_sidebar_panel',10,3);
```

Note that this works if you are  going to add the sidebars in a panel.
If you need to show them in a section (rather than a panel), then it will require some more coding. But I believe that can be done too.